# Encoding of JSOUP get title of web page

Tags: java, android, jsoup

How can I fix string `%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BE - Пошук Google` to normal russian like : `моа - Пошук Google`

I get it from title from downloaded page, but seems like it is in wrong encoding.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
     String s = "%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BE - Пошук Google";
     System.out.println(URLDecoder.decode(s, "UTF-8"));
    }
```

it will print:

```
моо - Пошук Google
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code while getting document.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("url").get();
doc.charset(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```